# Есть ли возможность средствами node.js упаковать файлы в rar?

Tags: node.js, rar

Есть ли возможность средствами node.js упаковать файлы в rar?

Comment: Нет, формат закрытый. А вот zip можно.

Comment: @Suvitruf Почему не в ответы?

Comment: @Suvitruf может все таки можно? Искал ответ в google и на русском и на английском - так и не нашел.

Comment: @AK действительно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rar - закрытый формат, из коробки не получится.

Но вы можете установить `rar` утилиту в систему и вызывать её:

```
rar myfile.dat compressed.rar
```

Для этого воспользуйтесь [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

Comment: спасибо, теперь я понял почему гугл молчит, и почему в npm нету rar архиватора)))

Comment: @владмочоний зачем именно rar? Почему не zip?

Comment: требование заказчика.)